# emberjs controller's needs returns undefined and unable to access controller.content

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use Emberjs *needs api** to access Postscontroller from a comments controller. The PostController is backed by a route while I don't want the comment's controller to have a route.

In the comments controller, I have **needs: ['posts', 'postsShow']**.  From the comments controller, when I run console log with the following commands,:

```
    console.log( this.get('controllers.postsShow') );

    console.log( this.get('controllers.posts') );
```

**In the console I see:**

```
<EmBlog.PostsShowController:ember396> { target=<EmBlog.Router:ember316>, namespace=EmBlog, store=<EmBlog.Store:ember336> 

 <EmBlog.PostsController:ember304> { target=<EmBlog.Router:ember316>, namespace=EmBlog, store=<EmBlog.Store:ember336>
```

**However, when I try to access the controller content** for PostsShowController or PostsController, it always returns **post undefined**. These are various approaches I have tried and still got **post undefined**:

```
 var post = this.get('controllers.posts').get('content');

              or

var post =  this.get('controllers.posts.content');
```

**Also I tried to get 'comments' from the content like this:**

```
var post = this.get('controllers.posts')

var comment = post.get('comments');

          or

 comment = post.comments;
```

**I still got the error:**

```
 TypeError: post is undefined  comment = post.comments;

 TypeError: post is undefined var comment = post.get('comments');
```

**Which also means:**

```
  var post =  this.get('controllers.posts.model').get('store.transaction');

  also returns post is  undefined.
```

**This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzseQ/) and the relevant section of the code is pasted below:**

```
    EmBlog.PostsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
       content: null
    });

    EmBlog.PostsShowController =
       Ember.ObjectController.extend({
       content: null
    });


   EmBlog.CommentNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

       needs: ['posts', 'postsShow'],    
       isAddingNew: false,

      addComment: function(body){

           console.log( this.get('controllers.postsShow') );

           console.log( this.get('controllers.posts') );

           var post =  this.get('controllers.posts.content');
               store = post.get('store.transaction');

      }

  });
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `posts` controller is empty.  You are filling the posts in `PostIndexController`, not `PostsController`.

Check the route:

```
EmBlog.PostsRoute  = Ember.Route.extend({
});

EmBlog.PostsIndexRoute  = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return EmBlog.Post.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

So you should either do

```
needs:  ['postsIndex', 'postsShow']
```

and then:

```
this.get('controllers.postsIndex.content')
```

or fix your route:

```
EmBlog.PostsRoute  = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return EmBlog.Post.find();
  }
});

EmBlog.PostsIndexRoute  = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('posts');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzseQ/1/)

Comment: many thanks for helping out. When I place a console.log on the variable holding store, it returns **TypeError: post.get is not a function store = console.log(post.get('store.transaction') );**. The **[fiddle from you updated to show this](http://jsfiddle.net/mzseQ/2/)**. Do you have an idea why this is. This might be the reason why **clicking addComment** doesn't return the comment form as per this older **[jsfiddle with similar code](http://jsfiddle.net/CD9ck/4/)** which displays the comment form when we click on **addComment** except it **doesn't create the comment** when submitted. Thanks.

Comment: Many issues with that:  
- you can't do variable = console.log(something), you have to do variable = something.
- if u want one post, you need `postsShow.content` not `postsIndex.content`
- `post.get('store.transaction')` is just a function.  You either need `transaction = this.get('store').transaction()` or `post.get('transaction')`

Comment: thanks so much for the your patience and for the useful insight you are providing. I corrected the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzseQ/3/)** in line with your suggestions above. All errors are gone and **only one problem remaining**. When I click on **addComment** it doesn't bring up the comment form and in the console i see **undefined**. Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: the form is now showing up when i click **addComment** with this latest edit to a more updated **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzseQ/4/)** but it will still not create a comment when the form is submitted and just returns **undefined**. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your time. I have accepted your answer as it answered the original question, so that anyone searching can know that bit now works. I have now moved **the question on why submitting the comment form returns undefined** to a **[new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617967/emberjs-and-ember-data-creating-record-via-form-submission-returns-undefined)**. I hope you can make suggestions there. Many thanks.