# emberjs and ember-data -creating record via form submission returns undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzseQ/5/)**. Everything works excepting that i can't create a new comment by submitting the comment's form. when i **submit a form the console  shows  undefined**. What I hope to achive is to grab an existing post and then create a comment that belongs to that post. So this the flow of things, a user will click on **post** then click a specific **post title** to display it and then click on **add comment** to comment on that post. It is important to note that at the moment, clicking on **add comment button** will return **undefined**.

*Relevant section of the code with the **addComment** and **save** methods.*

```
EmBlog.CommentNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

  needs: ['postsShow'],
  isAddingNew: false,

  addComment: function(body){

    post = this.get('controllers.postsShow.model');

    store = post.get('transaction');

    store.createRecord(EmBlog.Comment, {body: body});

    this.set('isAddingNew', true);
  },

 save: function(){
  console.log(this.store.commit());
 }  
});
```

**The relevant section from the handlebars template

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='comment/new'>
  {{#if controller.isAddingNew}}
    <form {{action save on='submit'}}>
    {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="body" placeholder="body"}}
    <button type="submit"> save comment </button>  
    </form>
  {{/if}} 
  <br/>
  <div>
    <button {{action addComment}} {{bindAttr disabled="isAddingNew"}}>
      Add Comment
   </button>
 </div>
</script>
```

**The comment form is submitted via 'posts/show template' using render**

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/show">
    <p> Comments</p>
    {{render 'comment/new' comments}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create the `Comment` record using:

```
var comment = EmBlog.Comment.createRecord()
```

or

```
var transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
var comment = transaction.createRecord(EmBlog.Comment);
```

You can either create the record before the user fills the form, and bind the values to that created record and only commit when the user clicks save, or you can bind the text area to a controller property, and create and commit the record after the user clicks on save.

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzseQ/6/) with the second approach.

Comment: you are gentleman scholar. Many thanks, for solving this pain point of mine in my emberjs journey.

Comment: You have done enough but incase you still have a few minutes and just for learning sake, do you know why clicking the back button after creating a new comment displays **Error: the id property must be defined for fixture {"id":0,"title":"first title","body":"first body","comments":["ember423"]}** even when the id property is already defined in the fixture. Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can't have id:'0', try id:'1'

Comment: Very true. Changing it to 1 removed the errors. Many thanks and enjoy your day

Answer (score 1):

Great post. Just one remark. With the latests libraries, deletePost does not work ...

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'deleteRecord' of undefined

SOLUTION:

```
destroyPost: function (post) {
  post.one('didDelete', this, function () {
    this.transitionTo('posts.index');
  });
  post.deleteRecord();
  post.get('transaction').commit();
}
```